# vscode viewContainer mixed views

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I want to create an extension with a customized viewContainer which contains several views like webview and tree view.

The desired UI is as follows:

[image: Expected UI]

Is there any way to achieve this?

Here's what I have achieved, but still cannot get rid of the header bar in the webview.

[image: Current UI]

Comment: use a `WebviewView`, you have total control of what happens

Comment: Thank you, is there any example of using `WebviewView`? I still want to leverage the treeview's ability for tree structured data.

Comment: if you want tree structured data in your WebviewView you have to implement it yourself of use a framework that has it. Look in the collection of VSC samples

Comment: Thank you, I'll go with a single webview. Multiple mixed views in a viewContainer seems not possible to meet the desired UI with my case.

Answer (score 0):

What you call the header bar is the section header in the sidebar sections. This is controlled by VS Code and does not depend on what you have in a section. The only thing you can do to change the appearance is to leave the name of the view empty in your package.json:

```json
"contributes": {
    "views": {
        "myView": {
            "id": "your.view.id",
            "name": "",
        }
    }
}
```

but this will not prevent the section header to show up. It's just empty instead.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I have currently achieved. It just shows nothing of the header text, but the header bar is still there. Maybe, I should implemented with a single webview as @rioV8 suggested.